# generating project with yeoman

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I m trying to generate a the project with Yeoman from a template. I can copy all files from portanova template folder but i cant copy a file from an other template folder and add it in my project. It gives me exception " illegal operation on a directory".
What i m doing wrong ?

```
 this.log(yosay(
      'Welcome to the fantabulous ' + chalk.red('') + ' generator!'
    ));

    var prompts = [{
      name: 'projectName',
      message: 'What do you want to call the new project ?'
    },{
      name: 'answer',
      message: 'would you like to add File X ?'
    }

    ];

    this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
      this.projectName = props.projectName;
      this.answer = props.answer;
      done();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  writing: function () {

    this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('portanova_template'),
      this.destinationPath(this.projectName)
    );
    if(this.answer=='yes'){
      this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath('externalTemplate/fileX.html'),
        this.destinationPath(this.projectName+'/app')
      );
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check wether you have the right to copy from the 2nd folder, if not try this :

```
chmod -R 777 /Your/folder
```

Ps (-R : to work on a folder)